# Server Socket in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

What is an alternative to TServerSocket and TClientSocket (like in Delphi 7), in Delphi 2010?
I'm really not sure what to use, since this is what I would like to do:

For server side:

```
ServerSocket1.Port := 23;
```

For client side:

```
ClientSocket1.Port :=  23;  
ClientSocket1.Host :=  'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
```

What will a alternative be for this in Delphi 2010?

Comment: The first Google hit on 'TServerSocket' is [this About.com article](http://delphi.about.com/b/2008/07/14/where-to-locate-the-missing-tserversocket-and-tclientsocket-delphi-components.htm).

Comment: You might also be interested in [another such article](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa020403a.htm).

Comment: *hides face*. Damn, sorry. I searched, but couldn't find anything relevant. Guess I used the wrong phrase. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently `TSocketServer` and `TClientSocket` ship with Delphi, [but they just hide it](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/no_serverscoket.htm):

> - From the Delphi IDE menu select Component - Install Packages,
> - Click Add, in the Install Packages dialog,
> - In the Add Design Package dialog, browse to your "RAD Studio\5.0\bin" folder (for Delphi 2007) and select dclsockets100.bpl, then click Open.
> - Click OK.

i would never have guessed that <strike>Borland</strike><strike>Imprise</strike><strike>CodeGear</strike>Embarcadero put them on the DVD.

Answer (score 4):

Recommended alternatives include Indy, ICS, Synapse, RealThinSDK, and just about any other socket library for Delphi.